# How does Passport.js handle sessions?

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I am having trouble understanding the concept of sessions for a web application. I am running a Node.js server with Express 3.0.

### Requirements:

- Create a session for each user that logs in
- Store this session and use it for validating if the user is already logged in (prevent two devices using the same user at the same time)
- Limit access to certain pages (by matching session ID to some other data)

Where does passport store sessions?

Comment: If you're using Express/Connect, Passport can use their [`session` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html). Checkout http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/, esp. "Middleware" and "Sessions."

Comment: @crzrcn : Hi, I couldn't quite figure out how to prevent a user to login from two machines in the accepted answer. Could you please shed some light on this?

Comment: @mystikacid I don't use Passport anymore nor do I even remember I had asked this question. 

Anyhow, you'd want to store sessions for your users somewhere. That session value that you store should be able to indicate if the session is active, and to what user it belongs. When your app receives another session creation action that maps to the same user, then your app should delete or inactivate all other sessions for the same user.

As for Passport specific usage, I can't help you there.

Comment: @crzrcn : Nevermind...the logic helps nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stores user sessions (with express or connect) in `req.user`.

Keep in mind this is different from the express session middleware, which can store whatever you want in `req.session`.

To persist your user session with passport, use passport's middleware:

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

then access the user like so:

```
function someRoute(req, res, next) {
  // req.user = the user of this session
}
```

Comment: What does this line `app.use(passport.session())` do then? If passport uses express.session's.

Comment: I didn't write passport, but I would guess that it allows passport to leverage express.session to maintain state. Express.session uses an external session store so that you can maintain sessions across processes, machines, and networks.